# Line Chart path in D3 JS not displaying Properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

I am trying to implement a line chart through this function. when I try to add the path, the path alone is not getting displayed. any help would be appreciated. (last 10 lines of the code add the path to the graph)

```
function drawLineChart(country) {
  console.log(countryValueMap[country])
   var margin = {top: 60, right: 110, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right + 50,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom + 50;
    // document.getElementById("my_dataviz").innerHTML = "";
    const lineSvg = d3.select("#linechart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    const x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0 , width])
  .domain([new Date(1958,0,1), new Date(2011,0,1)])

lineSvg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5).tickFormat(d => d.getFullYear()))

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,countryMaxValueMap[country]])
  .range([height, 0])
lineSvg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisRight(y).tickSize(width)).call(g => g.select(".domain")
        .remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", "2,2"))
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick text")
        .attr("x", 4)
        .attr("dy", -4));


    lineSvg.append("path")
      .datum(countryValueMap[country])
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year) })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.gdp) })
        )
}
```

When I try to execute the above code, this is the output I am getting.

[image: This is The Output I am getting]

I tried logging the value of d3.year and d3.gdp and the variable works fine.

Comment: Can you share `countryValueMap`? Given that the line is at 1970 (the start of epoch time), it looks like something is wrong with the how the years are represented in your data. Since you are using a `scaleTime`, `d.year` must be a date object. It can't just be an integer representing the year.

Comment: @Dan That worked, Thanks , post it as reply . i will mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the line is at 1970 (the start of epoch time), it looks like something is wrong with the how the years are represented in your data. Since you are using a `scaleTime`, `d.year` must be a date object. It can't just be an integer representing the year.